# Can't load second iframe in html page

Tags: html, iframe

I want to load 2 iframes in the same page. The first iframe loads normally but the second never loads(i tried a lot of urls and i tested in on safari, chrome, firefox, but nothing)
Here is the code

```
   <div align="center">



        <iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="50px" width="500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframeupload" name="frame1"/><br />
          <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" name="frame2" width="500px" height="50px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="iframedomain"/>


</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple, Iframes should be closed like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="50px" width="500px" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" id="iframeupload" name="frame1"></iframe>
```

not like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="50px" width="500px" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" id="iframeupload" name="frame1" />
```